# how to display state counties in d3

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to display a county map of WV in D3. I have located a GeoJSON file on the internet titled "wv-counties.json" from https://github.com/geary/polygonzo/tree/master/shapes/json. When I look at this file, the first few lines are as follows:

```
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "properties": 
  {
     "kind": "state",
    "state": "wv"
  },
 "features": [
  {"type":"Feature","bbox":[-80.2283,38.9446,-79.8121,39.3006],"properties":{"kind":"county","name":"Barbour","state":"wv","center":[-80.0202,39.1228],"centroid":[-80.0018,39.1309]},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-79.9764,39.2622],[-79.8942,39.3006],[-79.8121,39.2294],[-79.8230,39.1144],[-79.8942,38.9720],[-80.0859,38.9446],[-80.0531,38.9774],[-80.0531,39.0377],[-80.1297,39.0377],[-80.2283,39.1144],[-80.2228,39.1691],[-80.1681,39.2403]]]]}},
```

There is a line for each county.

In my javascript I have a line:

```
d3.json("wv-counties.json", function(error, wv)
```

after which, I can print the wv object to the console and see that it was loaded.

How would I go about displaying this file?

I have tried this:

```
svg.append("path")
.data(wv)
.attr("class", "county-border")
.attr("d", path);
```

But just get a blank screen.

I have also tried this:

```
svg.append("path")
    .datum(topojson.mesh(wv))
.attr("class", "county-border")
.attr("d", path);
```

But this generates an error (Most likely because the file is not a TopoJSON file).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend this tutorial as a good introduction to mapping with geoJson and d3:

http://www.schneidy.com/Tutorials/MapsTutorial.html

That said, here's some code to get you started:

```
var svg = d3.select('#wv-map'), // or however you want to select and/or create your svg
  group = svg.append('g'), 
  projection = d3.geo.albersUsa();

d3.json("wv-counties.json", function(error, wv) {

  group.selectAll('path')
    .data(wv.features)
    .enter().append('path')
    .attr('d', d3.geo.path().projection(projection))
    .style('fill', 'silver')
    .style('stroke', 'white')
    .style('stroke-width', 1);    

});
```

The key points are that, after loading the geoJson data, you need to data bind it using the `enter` selection and draw the county paths using a `projection` that translates the geographic coordinates from your data into coordinates in your svg.

Comment: I tried your edits and it's starting to take shape. I am seeing output but the lines are not exactly correct. It's difficult to explain without some images though. It is possible for me to post some screenshots here on stack overflow?

Comment: Glad that it's getting closer ... Try this for screenshots: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91716/how-to-upload-screenshots

Comment: ok, I'm making progress now. Appreciate the help. Turned out that I needed your edits and a better data source. Your edits above and data from http://eric.clst.org/Stuff/USGeoJSON were the solution.

Comment: The link to this tutorial is not available.